# Too many open files<How to find which java file is causing the leakage>

Tags: java, unix

All of sudden,we are encoutering the below error in our system. 
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /web/wasapps/EventLog.log (Too many open files)

I am assuming that there are some files which are not closed but  I am not able to find which java file is causing the leakage. Kindly help me please on this..

Unlimit set is as below:

```
time(seconds)        unlimited
file(blocks)         unlimited
data(kbytes)         unlimited
stack(kbytes)        unlimited
memory(kbytes)       32768
coredump(blocks)     unlimited
nofiles(descriptors) 2000
threads(per process) unlimited
processes(per user)  unlimited
```

Stack Trace :

SystemErr     R Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
 /web/wasapps/EventLog.log (Too many open files)

```
at java.io.FileOutputStream.openAppend(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:203)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:128)
at com.abc.ci.common.LogManager.writeIntoFile(Unknown Source)
at com.abc.ci.common.LogManager.writeLogFile(Unknown Source)
at com.abc.ci.common.LogManager.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.abc.ci.RANdc.common.CIFAdapter.postRequestForHashMap(Unknown Source)
at com.abc.ci.RANdc.UserInqDataTranslator.translate(Unknown Source)
at com.abc.ci.RANdc.UserInqProcessor.UserInq(UserInqProcessor.java:187)
at com.abc.ci.RANdc.srvprov.UserInqXYHostSrvProv.executeService(Unknown Source)
at com.abc.fiapi.common.XYHostServiceExecutor.execute(Unknown Source)
at com.abc.ci.RAN.ejb.RANModuleEJBBean.executeService(Unknown Source)
at com.abc.ci.srvprov.FRANModuleBeanLookUpServiceProvider.executeService(Unknown Source)
at com.abc.ci.abc.app.abcServiceExecutor.executeService(Unknown Source)
at com.abc.ci.abc.app.abcMessageExecutor.executeService(Unknown Source)
at com.abc.ci.abc.app.abcMessageExecutor.executeMessage(Unknown Source)
at com.abc.ci.abc.app.abcSyncMessageExecutor.processMessage(Unknown
```

Comment: How about `lsof`?

Comment: @biziclop lsof -p "pid" will list all the process running i believe.But how can I find which java file is opening the file. Any inputs please.

Comment: Well, the list of files open should be a clue. Failing that, `jvisualvm` could be used to find all instances of `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream` and which objects hold a reference to thme. It's not perfect but it's a start.

Comment: if your problem has occurred "all of the sudden", the first place to look is at the code/packages/programs etc that have changed most recently. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

jstack (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jstack.html) can also help identify what the issue is here. `lsof` will give you the pid and you can run `jstack < pid >` to dump stack traces for all of the threads.  Assuming you're opening the file in a loop somewhere you might catch a stack that shows where if you take a few jstacks.

Another solution is to use something like JMockit (http://jmockit.googlecode.com) to mock the FileOutputStream constructor to dump the stack whenever your file is opened.  Just add this code to your main method:

```
final String TARGET_FILE = "/web/wasapps/EventLog.log";
new MockUp<FileOutputStream>()
{
    @Mock
    public $init(Invocation i, String name)
    {
        if (name.equals(TARGET_FILE))
        {
            new Exception().printStackTrace();
        }

        i.proceed();
    }
};
```